# Merging navbar and carousel in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if it would be possible to merge the carousel and navbar like in this example: https://heydays.no/.

I tried putting the carousel within the nav element but that didn't seem to work. Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light"">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WeDesign</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-pause="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1779487/pexels-photo-1779487.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1999463/pexels-photo-1999463.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like the link you have provided.

```css
a {
  color: black !important;
}

a:hover {
  color: black !important;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="navbar" style="background-color: transparent;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WeDesign</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" id="" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-pause="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1779487/pexels-photo-1779487.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1999463/pexels-photo-1999463.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```